# Web Service SOAP Client Works on Tomcat but no on IBM Web Sphere - validation error

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I have Web Service, which works well on Tomcat 7.0, (Java 7) but not on Web Sphere. Probably, there is problem with libraries, but I don't know, how to find out this App WAS Server specific problem.

Client Implementation use Spring WS SOAP a Spring WS Core:

```
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFaultException;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException;
...     
public KonverzeResponse convert(KonverzeRequest request)
            throws Exception, SoapFaultClientException, SoapFaultException {

        KonverzeResponse response = (KonverzeResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        if (response == null /* || response.getValue() == null */)
            throw new Exception("Response is empty.");

        return response/* .getValue() */;
    }
```

Tomcat issues success, WAS issues:

> [11/6/18 18:02:01:030 CET] 000000d8 SystemOut     O 2018-11-06 18:02:01,029 ERROR [WebContainer : 7] ComponentServiceFacadeImpl - Client Error, Failed to Accept Converted File or Other Error.
> org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: `Validation error`
> at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:776)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:602)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:372)
> at cz.legend.mzv.spi.ws.clients.convertor.ConvertorClient.convert(ConvertorClient.java:63)
> at cz.legend.mzv.spi.ws.clients.convertor.interfaces.ConvertorServiceImpl.convertFnFile(ConvertorServiceImpl.java:103)

Related documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO500000001DQQGA2/websphere-application-server
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_migrate_web20.html
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639407
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.websvcs.resources.websvcsMessages.html

Comment: English error message: "Client Error, Failed to Accept Converted File or Other Error."

Answer (score 0):

Validation error, in first plan means, that Request / Response is not in expected shape. First check Request according definition. Logger has option for enabling print Requests / Responses into the log. E.q. `log4j.properties` has options for Spring WS:

```
# Spring WS
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=DEBUG
```

Find out keyword `Envelope`, copy the content of Request and check it in some independent tool, which is for checking of SOAP Requests - e.q. SoapUI, etc.
If in response is `Validation error`, check the Request.

In my case, I omitted this step and focused on probably different incompatible libraries. It was mistake. The problem was in different behavior of code on Tomcat and Web Sphere - some resource was unreachable and there was bad treated Exception. Result was, that Requests on Tomcat and Web Sphere were different.